# Reasons for rejecting iPhone application by Apple store

Tags: ios, app-store

Can anybody help me out to know the possible reasons for which Apple store can reject or raise objection to submit any iPhone application.

Comment: As bad a the Palm platform was, at least anybody could write and sell apps for it.

Comment: @Kibbee: Except that they sold a lot less of those apps.

Comment: This question is off-topic because it is about App Store compliance, not a coding issue. Please see [Are developer-centric questions about application stores on topic for Stack Overflow?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/175701)

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Here are possible reasons (unofficial, [from here](http://10base-t.com/unofficial-appstore-rejection-criteria/)):

- **Vibration**.  It is not permitted to use continuous vibration in your apps - short bursts as warnings is all that is allowed.  Don’t bother trying to set up a timer to keep the vibration going, it will cause your app to be rejected.
- **Linking to private frameworks**.  This is obvious, but somehow in playing around with stuff we had linked to the MoviePlayer.framework.  That’s a no-no, and cost us about ten days while we unlinked that framework, recompiled, and then resubmitted.
- **Improper handling of editing in tableview cells**.  Also obvious, but be aware that if you enable table cell editing, you’ll have to manually specify which cells should respond to editing controls and which should not.  We had some random prefs cells in one of our early apps that were able to be swiped to bring up a ‘delete’ badge.  Of course it didn’t do anything, but Apple justly considered this poor design and rejected our app.
- **Icons**. Make sure the 57 pixel icon is identical to the 512 pixel version. Also, use a different icon if you are creating ‘lite’ and ‘pro’ versions of your app (i.e., free and paid). Using the same icon for both sends your app straight to … you guessed it … the bin.
- **Copying existing functionality**. This one is much more subtle and insidious, and has probably affected the great percentage of developers. In addition to the widely publicized Podcaster debacle, reports from user comments indicate that Apple is casting a wide net when looking for duplicated functionality. Mini web browsers, or apps that essentially show web pages, seem particularly vulnerable, even if they add new and/or useful functionality. Stay away from email clients as well.
- **Using appropriate keyboard type**. If your app asks for a phone number or other numeral-only input and you present a keyboard that also includes the possibility of entering standard alpha-numeric input … yep. (Thanks Jeremy1026)
- **Version numbers**. If your app is currently at ***version 0.99 or below***, you’d better consider giving it a promotion as Apple seems to prefer 1.0 and above. One of ours was recently rejected for being .016, with a message suggesting that our version number wasn’t even numeric. When we resubmitted the same app from scratch as version 1.0, it went through.
- **Network Reachability**. If your app requires any type of network access you need to make sure it works when that access isn't available. If it doesn't it will be rejected. Apple provides sample code to test this which you can use as-is in most cases: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html

And last, but not least:

- **Flatulence** Don’t even try. ;-) UPDATE: sorry, this seems to be outdated by now. Apple makes a lot of money now with "fart apps": [see this article](http://venturebeat.com/2008/12/23/iphone-fart-app-pulls-in-nearly-10000-a-day/).

**Edit:**

Here is a link to a recent article about [ten iPhone Apps That Didn't Make Apple's App Store](http://www.pcworld.com/article/159887/).

And a tip: Apple has a Mac app called *Application Loader* that you could install. Once you install it, it analyzes your app's zip file. It verifies all the certificates, icons, and other things are correct *before* submitting to Apple. Using the Application Loader  minimizes your chances of app rejection.

---

Another interesting resource: [App Store Roundtable: Transparency and the Approval System](http://theappleblog.com/2009/05/06/app-store-roundtable-transparency-and-the-approval-system/) (appleblog.com)

---

Yet another edit:

New rules by February 2010: **"No Swimsuits, No Skin, And No Innuendo"** (source: [TechCrunch article](http://techcrunch.com/2010/02/20/app-store-rules-sexy/), W[obble author's blog](http://chillifresh.com/2010/02/20/5000-apps-banned-the-new-rules/))

By the way: during the iPhone 3.0 preview event (march 2009), an Apple spokesman told that 96% of all submitted application were approved.

Comment: You might find this interesting regarding your second point: http://daringfireball.net/2008/11/google_mobile_uses_private_iphone_apis

Comment: I would also add another one to that list: random. Apple once asked me to resubmit my binary with no changes at all...my guess is they lost it or something.

Answer (score 41):

[image]

Comment: You got 10 upvotes for a post containing only a 404 image without any kind of description?! makes me wonder what the image was.

Comment: That's a good point. ;) I'll see if I can get it working again.

Comment: And there we go. Enjoy, Kris.

Answer (score 10):

Apple have now (as of 9th September 2010) published their official list of app store review guidelines:

[appstore approval guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/)

(apple developer login required)

or a mirror here:

[app store guidelines](http://stadium.weblogsinc.com/engadget/files/app-store-guidelines.pdf)

Answer (score 5):

Will apple want to create an app like that in the future?  `If (yes) reject`.

Do you have a really awesome idea that apple may want to use in the future `if(yes) reject`

Comment: Why the down vote?  Not even going to leave a comment?

Answer (score 3):

Here's the video of the SDK announcement that describes Apple published list of rejection criteria:

[SDK Announcement](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dWynAHdVqnQ)

As others have noted, Apple also seem to have a bunch of other conditions that they don't publicise. Note that rejection notices are [now covered by the NDA](http://blog.wired.com/gadgets/2008/09/apple-imposes-n.html).

Answer (score 2):

I can't confirm this but it makes sense, but people are reporting their apps being rejected for being too simple or too trivial.

Comment: Which makes you wonder what was going on when Apple allowed all the bullshit Flashlights

Comment: Charlie, I actually have Flashlight on my first page on iPhone. Very handy at night.

Comment: "Too similar to a mobile browsing experience", even though every single app that doesn't use something weird like ARKit is similar to a mobile browsing experience.

Answer (score 1):

Just got a bounce for handling network outages badly.  If you connect to the network, be prepared to handle any error conditions that may come up.

Answer (score 1):

My paid version of app was rejected by appstore.

After Purchasing and downloading app first screen was **"User Agreement"** and when user taps on **" I agree**" only then he is able to continue using app.

Apple described the reason of rejection **"when user purchased app from appstore and download in phone then you must not restrict user to Agree with Agreement"** instead display your agreement before downloading app in iTunes.

Answer (score 0):

Amazingly, apps can get [rejected](http://forums.appleinsider.com/showthread.php?threadid=108499) for trying to keep their interface consistent with Apple's own apps. (ie, using pinch zoom/expand gestures)

Answer (score 0):

There is a site I know which can help you generate great advertising ideas with iPhone. see this site:
http://itunes.apple.com/app/adpack/id359562015?mt=8

Answer (score 0):

I submitted a paid app to app store but get rejected and i learned another possibility of app rejection

My app was Game Center enabled. When app starts first screen was login screen that prompt user to login through GameCenter to continue.

They rejected the app giving reason- As user will not be able to get services of your app unless he is not logged in with Game Center although he paid you to download app. You cannot restrict user to login through Game Center each time before app starts.

Answer (score 0):

From 1st May,2013 onwards if we don't support iPhone 5, your app will be rejected.So iPhone 5 support is must.