# Where can I find a detailed Apple App Store policy?

Tags: app-store

Including under which circumstances applications are rejected, and how much of a percentage Apple takes (widely distributed as 30%, though I can find no mention of it on their site).

Thanks!

Comment: I think the policy only exists inside Steve Jobs' head and he appears to be quite 'jekkyl and hyde' about it :-)

Comment: @Chris: Not an appropriate use for tags.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you go: https://i.stack.imgur.com/53ZxN.jpg

To be serious though, Apple has not published a definitive guide to the acceptance policy.  It sometimes seems arbitrary and unfounded and even sometimes contrary to what they have provided as their pseudo-policy.

From the iPhone developer agreement section 3.3:

Any Application developed using this SDK must comply with these criteria and requirements, as they may be modified by Apple from time to time:

APIs and Functionality:
3.3.1 Applications may only use Published APIs in the manner prescribed by Apple
and must not use or call any unpublished or private APIs.

3.3.2 An Application may not itself install or launch other executable code by any
means, including without limitation through the use of a plug-in architecture, calling other
frameworks, other APIs or otherwise. No interpreted code may be downloaded and used in
an Application except for code that is interpreted and run by Apple's Published APIs and builtin
interpreter(s).

3.3.3 Without Apple’s prior written approval, an Application may not provide, unlock or
enable additional features or functionality through distribution mechanisms other than the App
Store.

3.3.4 An Application may write data on a device only to the Application's designated
container area, except as otherwise specified by Apple.
User Interface and Data:

3.3.5 Applications must comply with the Human Interface Guidelines and other
Documentation provided by Apple.

3.3.6 Any form of user or device data collection, or image, picture or voice capture or
recording performed by the Application (collectively “Recordings”), and any form of user data,
content or information processing, maintenance, uploading, syncing, or transmission
performed by the Application (collectively "Transmissions") must comply with all applicable
privacy laws and regulations as well as any Apple program requirements related to such
aspects, including but not limited to any notice or consent requirements. In particular, a
reasonably conspicuous visual indicator must be displayed to the user as part of the
Application to indicate that a Recording is taking place.
SDK Agreement Page 5
Location Services and User Privacy:

3.3.7 For Applications that use location-based APIs or that collect, transmit, maintain,
process, share, disclose or otherwise use a user's personal information:

- You and the Application must comply with all applicable privacy and data collection laws
  and regulations with respect to any collection, transmission, maintenance, processing, use,
  etc. of the user's location data or personal information by the Application.
- Applications may not be designed or marketed for the purpose of harassing, abusing,
  stalking, threatening or otherwise violating the legal rights (such as the rights of privacy and
  publicity) of others.
- For Applications that use location-based APIs, such Applications may not be designed or
  marketed for real time route guidance; automatic or autonomous control of vehicles, aircraft,
  or other mechanical devices; dispatch or fleet management; or emergency or life-saving
  purposes.
- Applications may not use any robot, spider, site search or other retrieval application or
  device to scrape, retrieve or index services provided by Apple or its licensors, or to collect
  information about users for any unauthorized purpose.

3.3.8 Applications that offer location-based services or functionality must notify and
obtain consent from an individual before his or her location data is being collected,
transmitted or otherwise used by the Application.

3.3.9 Applications must not disable, override or otherwise interfere with any Appleimplemented
system alerts, warnings, display panels, consent panels and the like intended to
notify the user that the user's location data is being collected, transmitted, maintained,
processed or used, or intended to obtain consent for such use. If consent is withheld or
withdrawn, Applications may not collect, transmit, maintain, process or utilize the user's
location data.
Content and Materials:

3.3.10 Any master recordings and musical compositions embodied in Your Application
must be wholly-owned by You or licensed to You on a fully paid-up basis and in a manner
that will not require the payment of any fees, royalties and/or sums by Apple to You or any
third party. In addition, if Your Application will be distributed outside of the United States, any
master recordings and musical compositions embodied in Your Application (a) must not fall
within the repertoire of any mechanical or performing/communication rights collecting or
licensing organization now or in the future and (b) if licensed, must be exclusively licensed to
You for Your Application by each applicable copyright owner.

3.3.11 If Your Application includes or will include any other content, You must either
own all such content or have permission from the content owner to use it in Your Application.

3.3.12 Applications must not contain any obscene, pornographic, offensive or
defamatory content or materials of any kind (text, graphics, images, photographs, etc.), or
other content or materials that in Apple’s reasonable judgment may be found objectionable by
iPhone or iPod touch users.

3.3.13 Applications must not contain any malware, malicious or harmful code, program,
or other internal component (e.g. computer viruses, trojan horses, “backdoors”) which could
damage, destroy, or adversely affect other software, firmware, hardware, data, systems,
services, or networks.
SDK Agreement Page 6

3.3.14 If Your Application includes any FOSS, You agree to comply with all applicable
FOSS licensing terms. You also agree not to use any FOSS in the development of Your
Application in such a way that would cause the non-FOSS portions of the SDK to be subject
to any FOSS licensing terms or obligations.
Cellular Network:

3.3.15 If an Application requires or will have access to the cellular network, then
additionally such Application:

- Must comply with Apple's best practices and other guidelines on how Applications should
  access and use the cellular network;
- Must not in Apple's reasonable judgment excessively use or unduly burden network
  capacity or bandwidth;
- May not have Voice over Internet Protocol (VoIP) functionality using the cellular network.

Answer (score 1):

Check out this thread about app store rejections: [Reasons for rejecting iPhone application by Apple store](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/308479/reasons-for-rejecting-iphone-application-by-apple-store)

And yes Apple's cut is 30%

Answer (score -1):

You need to be a registered developer.  But the information is [here](http://developer.apple.com/webapps/).