# Why no iphone app linking contacts to calendar?

Tags: iphone, calendar, contacts

I am not a programmer.  I would pay for an application that allowed me to create a link between a calendar appointment and one or more of my contacts.  This seems like an obvious applications with a huge market>  Why is it not possible to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Because there's no public API to access the Calendar before 4.0.

If an app is to be pushed to AppStore, the SDK agreement must be followed. [One of the rules is](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/534586/where-can-i-find-a-detailed-apple-app-store-policy):

> **3.3.1.** Applications may only use Published APIs in the manner prescribed by Apple and must not use or call any unpublished or private APIs.

It is possible to do this distributing outside of the AppStore channel (e.g. via Cydia). You can check if it exists for jailbroken iDevices.

Answer (score 0):

If you synch with Google's Calendar and you create a new Event, you can invite anybody from your contact list.

Answer (score 0):

In the latest version of iOS 4.2 the **EKEvent** class contains the property *attendees*. It is still always nil and there's no default screen that uses this property but my guess is this is a preparation for something we should be seeing soon.