# iPhone app rejected upon section 3.3.3 (but what does it mean?)

Tags: iphone, app-store

I made an iPhone application that displays a couple of pictures from the internet
where you can comment on (iPhone sms bubble style )

My app was rejected because of:

> 1. We cannot post this version of your iPhone application to the App Store
>      because it violates section 3.3.3 of
>      the iPhone SDK Agreement;
>
> "Without Apple's prior written
>   approval, an Application may not
>   provide, unlock or enable additional
>   features or functionality through
>   distribution mechanisms other than the
>   iTunes Store."
>
> If you would like to provide an
>   invitation-only pre-release version of
>   your application to a group of
>   friends, then we encourage you to use
>   the Ad Hoc application distribution
>   method. Please go to the Distribution
>   Tab in the iPhone Developer Portal for
>   complete information on Ad Hoc
>   distribution.

But what does it mean? I surfed a little on the internet and found out that this covers applications that have similarity to applications by Apple?

Does anyone have experience with that? And know how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got official response from apple

> The website component of the
>   application is currently not available
>   to the general public. If you would
>   like to provide an invitation-only
>   pre-release version of your
>   application to a group of friends,
>   then we encourage you to use the Ad
>   Hoc application distribution method.
>
> Please go to the Distribution Tab in
>   the iPhone Developer Portal for
>   complete information on Ad Hoc
>   distribution.

Answer (score 0):

Section 3.3.3

> Without Apple’s prior written
>   approval, an Application may not
>   provide, unlock or enable additional
>   features or functionality through
>   distribution mechanisms other than the
>   App Store.

That means, for example, that you are not allowed to enable your application to download music or podcast files. Apple wants the owner of iPhones to use iTunes for that purpose.

You seem to violate that section since you're providing content from your site, even if you're downloading only pictures.

See this [blog entry about the PodCaster app](http://www.roughlydrafted.com/2008/09/15/sdk-333-the-iphone-podcaster-surprise-myth/):

> Podcaster quite obviously serves to
>   unlock a feature using a distribution
>   mechanism outside the iTunes Store.
>   This limitation would also include
>   apps that are designed to install
>   other apps independent of iTunes (such
>   as the Cydia jailbreak app - it’s not
>   in the Apps Store either), or any
>   other app that distributes song, TV,
>   or movie downloads or podcasts.

See also this answer here on Stack Overflow: [Reasons for rejecting iPhone application by Apple store](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/308479/reasons-for-rejecting-iphone-application-by-apple-store/308488#308488)

Comment: I disagree. 3.3.3 has nothing to do with data access at all. Tons of apps do just what you say: download music or podcast (RSS) files.

3.3.3 is about applications that require website registration to 'activate' for instance, in order to be 'fully featured'.

Comment: Yes you have to register online, there is no fee involved,but the website is not online yet, the application will run perfectly except placong comments.. What a hustle this is

Comment: Podcaster was eventually accepted as "RSS Player"; I agree with John, 3.3.3 has nothing to do with downloading content.

Answer (score 0):

Or they believe you used the open SDK to reuse the bubble control from the SMS app.

Can you post a screenshot?

Comment: hell no, i code that myself (i wish i could reuse that ) :) i used UITableView
how can you find that out ?