# iPhone play sound and also vibrate problem

Tags: objective-c, iphone

Here's my code to play sound:

```
NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Feel" ofType:@"mp3"];
NSURL *fileURL = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:filePath];
AVAudioPlayer *_audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:fileURL error:nil];
[_audioPlayer prepareToPlay];
_audioPlayer.numberOfLoops = -1;
[fileURL release];
_audioPlayer.currentTime = 0;
[_audioPlayer play];
```

My problem is to how to vibrate while playing this sound?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For vibration, read the "[System Sound Services Reference](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/AudioToolbox/Reference/SystemSoundServicesReference/Reference/reference.html)" documentation, especially the AudioServicesPlaySystemSound() method, with the constant kSystemSoundID_Vibrate.

Don't forget to link your project to the AudioToolbox framework.

Comment: This vibrates only 2-3 seconds. Is there a way to play continuos?

Comment: Maybe should I register a callback and invoke the function again?

Comment: Careful with that. Continuous vibration is a potential cause of rejection. Cf. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/308479/reasons-for-rejecting-iphone-application-by-apple-store

Comment: Than you think there is no way to vibrate during a sound plays?