# Can an universal application be rejected if it has no nib file?

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios, universal

I am creating an universal application (run on iPad and iPhone). I want to know if I am not create nib file for iPhone then is this possible that my application is rejected?

Comment: Did it get rejected already? If so, you should have gotten info on why. See also [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/308479/reasons-for-rejecting-iphone-application-by-apple-store).

Comment: no i am not submit it yet.I just want to know is this possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a .xib that you're using for both iPhone and iPad, there's nothing inherently wrong with that. I don't think you'll get rejected just for that.

But if your single .xib contains the main window and doesn't automatically resize to full screen -- i.e. only receives touch events in a 320x480 frame -- that could get your app rejected, since your app would have a malfunction when run on the iPad's 1024x768 screen.

Answer (score 0):

the screen difference is huge bw ipad and iphone .you cant have a iphone app on ipod .basically the difference is in interface builder for ipad and iphone .and u dont need additional nib file to make application there is default window nib file which u need