# Apple store reject my app (based jquery mobile)

Tags: ios, google-maps, jquery-mobile, app-store

Firs time i developed my app.it was only contain webview and it just call website to webview.They rejected my app.Then i looked for advice some developers said "you should IOS features"

So i used objective c..i used IOS features.Such as check network connection,splash,i replaced static form with IOS form...in my app i used all thing with native expect google map....for google map i used jquery mobile but they rejected again...there are some screenshoot from my iphone app and it is performance is good

screenshot 1:this is IOS native form
[image: screenshot 1:this is IOS native form]
screenshot 2 :this is IOS native form(bind with json rest service)
[image: screenshot 2 :this is IOS native form(bind with json rest service)]
screenshot 3: this is jquery mobile web page.i call this from IOS web view
[image: screenshot 3: this is jquery mobile web page.i call this from IOS web view]
screenshot 4: this is jquery mobile web page.i call this from IOS web view
[image: screenshot 4: this is jquery mobile web page.i call this from IOS web view]
screenshot 5: this is IOS Form
[image: screenshot 5: this is IOS Form]

this is their rejected issues and they Closed Communication so i can not ask them and mail them
what should i do?
Rejected

2.12: Apps that are not very useful, are simply web sites bundled as apps, or do not provide any lasting entertainment value may be rejected

10.6: Apple and our customers place a high value on simple, refined, creative, well thought through interfaces. They take more work but are worth it. Apple sets a high bar. If your user interface is complex or less than very good it may be rejected

Comment: The basic point is that the app doesn't seem to provide any value.  Apple only wants apps in the store that increase the value of the devices that they run on.  If it's a basic app like this or a "me too" kind of app, it will probably be rejected.  As it is already difficult enough to search the app store and get relevant results, adding more apps like this one will not help.  If you want to create great apps, please do.  If you just want to say that you've created an app, I think you may need to rethink it.

Comment: @iWasRobbed  my customer wants this app not me.. i am web developer in my opinion web mobile is best buy my customer want this app...and for this app i bought mac pc,apple developer account and i spent many time for learnin IOS and objective c(jsut writting easy form or webview is difficult for newbie) ...and in apple store there are many easy app.there are apps that is just one page or it is just image gallery...

Comment: The fact still remains that the app is really basic.  Unless you put more work into the app to add graphics and make it into a polished and useful application, Apple is not going to let this into the store.  If I was your customer, I would want something a lot more polished than what you are showing here.

Answer (score 4):

You need to carefully go over review guidelines 
https://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/approval/guidelines.html

and also human interface guidelines
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/Introduction/Introduction.html

First of all, you need to keep in mind its Apple and its Apple's App Store they have the right to reject your app, there are almost 1 million apps on the app store and they want your app to be ***useful, unique or provide some form of lasting entertainment.***

For 2.12 ; I can tell your Places view seems good I mean its a tableview and it seems useful to me,  but rest of the views are not good enough,  even though  they seem useful to you, apparently  to Apple they should have been much more useful, for example you can combine Location and Maps view easily. Try to provide more features and more interaction with app, not just simple webviews.

For 10.6: you need to carefully follow iOS Human Interface Guidelines fort example while you app gets data for your map view to populate and this takes a while and you dont show a progress hud to user that letting user know you are loading some data Apple probably will reject your app, or your user interaction freezes,disables or it is very complicated.

Comment: thanks... i will remove Location and i will combine it and maps ... and then i will reload i hope they will accept it

Comment: @user1688401 I dont think even with that they will accept your app, My point is make sure you provide some more useful features, it seems your whole app is a simple info page, there is no values to user or Apple.

Comment: @ Space Dust there is many app in apple store that is just a page or is just a image gallery.... instead of spent time for apple i will choose mobile web to apps but my customer wnat app

Comment: @user1688401 I know there are so simple apps out there, but I guess Apple's want to change it, they want each app to be unique, it is not a fair game you cant blame Apple. As I said before try to improve your app both UI design and functionality, try to put icons on your tab bar elements, when you submit your app describe more useful and exiting meta data description, change your contact form design try to improve it, I really dont know those are just suggestions. Bottom line is try to make valuable app not an info page app.

Answer (score 2):

It got rejected because it really doesn't do anything different than google maps. Unless it provides more services they will probably keep rejecting it

Comment: this is for famuos Hotel for their tourists ..it is do manything than google maps such as contains markers and pins...in this markers or pins there is info about historical places..there is  path that contains a package for tourist...there is famous restaurant info.....    http://i.stack.imgur.com/g4oFK.png

Comment: i want to tell apple store that is is not just google map..it is contains many marker that show historical places all info...this info inserted by Hotel but they closed communication:( ...and also it is not just map ...it is contain suggested places for tourist by admins ...and it is also contains contact form for taxi drivers...

Comment: @user1688401 It sure sounds like it does exactly what Google Maps does... I can find everything you just described via Google & Google Maps.  You're essentially bundling website info into an app and hoping they don't notice.

Comment: @iWasRobbed calling web page from webview is forbidden by apple? other forms such as places list,sqlash,contact forms are native...just map is web page

Answer (score 1):

Here's another stackoverflow post explaining the reasons why Apple rejects applications: [Reasons for rejecting iPhone application by Apple store](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/308479/reasons-for-rejecting-iphone-application-by-apple-store)

I do not think yours have rejected as not being different from others, there are 1800 lanterns on the appstore, the information provided by Apple is insufficient to know why.

Comment: i wish they(apple) give  some descriptions or give screenshoot why they rejected it.