# Creation of custom xib view size in Xcode

Tags: iphone, xcode, interface-builder

We are creating an application which uses one view multiple times inside another view.

I have accomplished this by manipulating the default xib view size to look like the one in the picture below and then importing multiple instances of it inside my main view:

[image: Custom xib view size]

Everything seems to work fine inside the simulator, I'm just scared apple will reject the application when submitting it to the app store.

Is this an acceptible way of accomplishing the task or would apple reject the application?

*note, I havn't tested this on an actual iPhone, only in the simulator.*

Regards

Comment: I don't see why Apple will reject it. 
Based on what do you think Apple will reject it?

Comment: This is absolutely OK. There is no reason to reject your application because of this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No apple is not going to reject your application. I always make custom views this way. And reuse them. So Don't worry about it. I have done this thing in lots of apps and all are on app store. You can check this link for apple rejection criteria if you have any doubts. 
[Reasons for rejecting iPhone application by Apple store](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/308479/reasons-for-rejecting-iphone-application-by-apple-store) Happy Coding!

Comment: Great, I find this way of creating custom views very useful and clean. Thanks!